# Jenkins: How configure the Local Maven Repository through the settings.xml file

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have installed `Maven 3.3.9` where the `settings.xml` file has configured the `<localRepository>` to a location different than `~/.m2/repository`. It works how is expected.

For `Jenkins 2.x` through the `Manage Jenkins` management menu option, in the `Configure System` option. I can see the `Maven Project Configuration` section, where there exists the `Local Maven Repository` option with a select box with three options:

- Default (~/.m2/repository)
- Local to the executor
- Local to the workspace

**Note:** the goal is reuse the same *custom repository location* defined in the `settings.xml` file, it for any Jenkin's `Job`. Of course it for any Java or Spring project working with Maven.

These three values always appear even when:

- through the `Manage Jenkins` management menu option, in the `Global Tool Configuration` option I have defined in the `Maven Configuration` section the `Default settings provider` and `Default global settings provider` settings referring to the same `settings.xml` file.
- again in `Configure System` option in the `Global properties` section for `Environment variables` section I have created the `M2_USER_HOME` *key* referring to the same *custom repository location* defined in the `settings.xml` file.

What extra configuration is need it to accomplish the goal?